# read a text file which has key value pairs and convert each line as one dictionary using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file (one.txt) that contains an arbitrary number of key‐value pairs (where the key and value are separated by a `=` – e.g. `1=8`). Here are some examples:

```
1=88|11=1438|15=KKK|45=00|45=00|21=66|86=a
4=13|11=1438|49=DDD|8=157.73|67=00|45=00|84=b|86=a
6=84|41=18|56=TTT|67=00|4=13|45=00|07=d
```

I need to create a DataFrame with a list of dictionaries, with each row as one dictionary in the list like so:

```
[{1:88,11:1438,15:kkk,45:7.7....},{4:13,11:1438....},{6:84,41:18,56:TTT...}]

df = pd.read_csv("input.txt",names=['text'],header=None)
data = df['text'].str.split("|")
names=[  y.split('=') for x in data for y in x]
ds=pd.DataFrame(names)
print ds
```

How can I create a dictionary for each line by splitting on the `=` symbol?

It should be one row and multiple columns.
The DataFrame should have all keys as rows and values as columns.

Example:

```
1 11 15 45 21 86 4 49 8 67 84 6 41 56 45 07
88 1438 kkk 00 66 a
na 1438 na .....
```

Comment: How many rows/columns are you expecting the resultant dataframe to be?

Comment: it should be keys as rows and columns as values

Comment: i need list to be like this each line as one dictionary [{1:88,11:1438,15:kkk,45:7.7....},{4:13,11:1438....},{6:84,41:18,56:TTT...}]

Answer (score 0):

I think performing a [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) would work.  Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.txt",names=['text'],header=None)
data = df['text'].str.split("|")
names=[  y.split('=') for x in data for y in x]
ds=pd.DataFrame(names)
ds = ds.pivot(columns=0).fillna('')
```

The `.fillna('')` removes the `None` values.  If you'd like to replace with `na` you can use `.fillna('na')`.

Output:

```
ds.head()

   1
0 07   1    11   15 21 4 41  45 49 56 6 67 8 84 86
0     88
1         1438
2               KKK
3                            00
4                            00
```

For space I didn't print the entire dataframe, but it does column indexing based on the key and then values based on the values for each line (preserving the dict by line concept).