# Using Python to populate Pandas Dataframe with spare CSV data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a delimited text file that looks like the following:

```
foo_14:14896|foo_23:17988|foo_16:1611|foo_5:14729|foo_6:13008|foo_2:19548|foo_8:2565
foo_18:13236|foo_18:6127|foo_14:5996
foo_4:12561|foo_24:20010|foo_15:20227|foo_6:3489|foo_8:19129|foo_1:2589|foo_25:5204|foo_19:18113|foo_3:20030|foo_16:12739|foo_5:5494  
foo_23:3606|foo_13:22588|foo_5:15104|foo_12:3307|foo_16:2039|foo_14:21537|foo_1:13178|foo_20:19090|foo_2:1140   
foo_5:10620|foo_21:11142|foo_22:13379|foo_1:16132|foo_10:9330|foo_23:13913|foo_6:8314|foo_13:4967    
foo_13:4891|foo_5:22715|foo_2:12098|foo_8:18634|foo_23:1341|foo_4:13995|foo_16:2923|foo_10:13663|foo_7:22939|foo_14:16711|foo_25:17824  
foo_22:8180|foo_1:11974|foo_7:6660|foo_17:17839|foo_10:3605|foo_8:22439|foo_6:15494|foo_11:17924|foo_18:17351|foo_20:16627|foo_14:9223|foo_13:2538|foo_16:19077 
foo_12:11381|foo_24:541|foo_12:13106|foo_7:6459|foo_11:6398|foo_14:23127|foo_9:15701
```

I'm looking to populate a Pandas DF where the different values of foo_14, foo_23 etc are ultimately the column labels and the value proceeding the : the specific data of that cell.  Each line of the text file represents a new row within the DF.  Are there any examples that one could point me to in order to steer me to a coding solution.  Many thanks ahead of time.

Belg

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225358/read-a-text-file-which-has-key-value-pairs-and-convert-each-line-as-one-dictiona

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("text.txt",names=['text'],header=None)
data = df['text'].str.split("|")
names=[  y.split(':') for x in data for y in x]
ds=pd.DataFrame(names)
ds = ds.pivot(columns=0).fillna('')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225609/6660373)

Comment: That's very close, thank you. However, each entry is now on it own row.  is there a way to get foo 14, 23, 16, 5, 6, 2 and 8 all on their own row by chance?

Comment: That's possible

Comment: How would one go about doing this?

Comment: groupby transpose it and use the same logic.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with that, how would we re-write the code above to groupby and transpose that?

Comment: Can you ask a separate question with the expected output? Because this will lead to another question not related to this one.

Comment: question asked and answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343310/using-python-to-populate-pandas-dataframe-with-sparse-csv-data