# Using Python to populate Pandas Dataframe with sparse CSV data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, sparse-matrix

I have the following text file that looks like the following:

```
foo_14:14896|foo_23:17988|foo_16:1611|foo_5:14729|foo_6:13008|foo_2:19548|foo_8:2565
foo_18:13236|foo_17:6127|foo_14:5996
foo_4:12561|foo_24:20010|foo_15:20227|foo_6:3489|foo_8:19129|foo_1:2589|foo_25:5204|foo_19:18113|foo_3:20030|foo_16:12739|foo_5:5494  
foo_23:3606|foo_13:22588|foo_5:15104|foo_12:3307|foo_16:2039|foo_14:21537|foo_1:13178|foo_20:19090|foo_2:1140   
foo_5:10620|foo_21:11142|foo_22:13379|foo_1:16132|foo_10:9330|foo_23:13913|foo_6:8314|foo_13:4967    
foo_13:4891|foo_5:22715|foo_2:12098|foo_8:18634|foo_23:1341|foo_4:13995|foo_16:2923|foo_10:13663|foo_7:22939|foo_14:16711|foo_25:17824  
foo_22:8180|foo_1:11974|foo_7:6660|foo_17:17839|foo_10:3605|foo_8:22439|foo_6:15494|foo_11:17924|foo_18:17351|foo_20:16627|foo_14:9223|foo_13:2538|foo_16:19077 
foo_12:11381|foo_24:541|foo_12:13106|foo_7:6459|foo_11:6398|foo_14:23127|foo_9:15701
```

using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("text.txt",names=['text'],header=None)
data = df['text'].str.split("|")
names=[  y.split(':') for x in data for y in x]
ds=pd.DataFrame(names)
ds = ds.pivot(columns=0).fillna('')
```

I get output that looks like the following:

```
0  foo_1 foo_10 foo_11 foo_12 foo_13 foo_14 foo_15 foo_16 foo_17 foo_18 foo_19 foo_2 foo_20 foo_21 foo_22 foo_23 foo_24 foo_25 foo_3 foo_4  foo_5  foo_6 foo_7 foo_8     foo_9
0                                     14896
1                                                                                                          17988
2                                                    1611
3                                                                                                                                           14729
4                                                                                                                                                  13008
..   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   ...   ...    ...    ...   ...   ...       ...
64                      13106
65                                                                                                                                                        6459
66                6398
67                                    23127
68                                                                                                                                                                    15701
```

However, I would like to see each of the data fields on the same line.  such as:

```
foo_14, foo_23, foo_16, foo_5, foo_6, foo_2 and foo_8 all appearing in row 0
foo_18, foo_17 and foo_14 should all appear in row 1
etc etc...
```

Instead of one row per entry I'd like to bulk them up to read as such

```
0  foo_1 foo_10 foo_11 foo_12 foo_13 foo_14 foo_15 foo_16 foo_17 foo_18 foo_19 foo_2 foo_20 foo_21 foo_22 foo_23 foo_24 foo_25 foo_3 foo_4  foo_5  foo_6 foo_7 foo_8     foo_9
0                                     14896          1611                       19548                      17988                        14729  13008           2565

etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, if I understand you correctly:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txtfile = StringIO("""foo_14:14896|foo_23:17988|foo_16:1611|foo_5:14729|foo_6:13008|foo_2:19548|foo_8:2565
foo_18:13236|foo_17:6127|foo_14:5996
foo_4:12561|foo_24:20010|foo_15:20227|foo_6:3489|foo_8:19129|foo_1:2589|foo_25:5204|foo_19:18113|foo_3:20030|foo_16:12739|foo_5:5494  
foo_23:3606|foo_13:22588|foo_5:15104|foo_12:3307|foo_16:2039|foo_14:21537|foo_1:13178|foo_20:19090|foo_2:1140   
foo_5:10620|foo_21:11142|foo_22:13379|foo_1:16132|foo_10:9330|foo_23:13913|foo_6:8314|foo_13:4967    
foo_13:4891|foo_5:22715|foo_2:12098|foo_8:18634|foo_23:1341|foo_4:13995|foo_16:2923|foo_10:13663|foo_7:22939|foo_14:16711|foo_25:17824  
foo_22:8180|foo_1:11974|foo_7:6660|foo_17:17839|foo_10:3605|foo_8:22439|foo_6:15494|foo_11:17924|foo_18:17351|foo_20:16627|foo_14:9223|foo_13:2538|foo_16:19077 
foo_12:11381|foo_24:541|foo_12:13106|foo_7:6459|foo_11:6398|foo_14:23127|foo_9:15701""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, names=['text'])

#df_out = df['text'].str.split('|', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('(:\d+)', '', regex=True))
```

Improvement by @Chris in comments below.

```
df_out = df['text'].str.split('|', expand=True).replace('(:\d+)', '', regex=True)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
       0       1       2       3       4       5       6           7         8       9         10      11       12
0  foo_14  foo_23  foo_16   foo_5   foo_6   foo_2   foo_8        None      None    None      None    None     None
1  foo_18  foo_17  foo_14    None    None    None    None        None      None    None      None    None     None
2   foo_4  foo_24  foo_15   foo_6   foo_8   foo_1  foo_25      foo_19     foo_3  foo_16   foo_5      None     None
3  foo_23  foo_13   foo_5  foo_12  foo_16  foo_14   foo_1      foo_20  foo_2       None      None    None     None
4   foo_5  foo_21  foo_22   foo_1  foo_10  foo_23   foo_6  foo_13          None    None      None    None     None
5  foo_13   foo_5   foo_2   foo_8  foo_23   foo_4  foo_16      foo_10     foo_7  foo_14  foo_25      None     None
6  foo_22   foo_1   foo_7  foo_17  foo_10   foo_8   foo_6      foo_11    foo_18  foo_20    foo_14  foo_13  foo_16 
7  foo_12  foo_24  foo_12   foo_7  foo_11  foo_14   foo_9        None      None    None      None    None     None
```

---

Changed input data for row 7 to make foo_12 unique on this row:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txtfile = StringIO("""foo_14:14896|foo_23:17988|foo_16:1611|foo_5:14729|foo_6:13008|foo_2:19548|foo_8:2565
foo_18:13236|foo_17:6127|foo_14:5996
foo_4:12561|foo_24:20010|foo_15:20227|foo_6:3489|foo_8:19129|foo_1:2589|foo_25:5204|foo_19:18113|foo_3:20030|foo_16:12739|foo_5:5494  
foo_23:3606|foo_13:22588|foo_5:15104|foo_12:3307|foo_16:2039|foo_14:21537|foo_1:13178|foo_20:19090|foo_2:1140   
foo_5:10620|foo_21:11142|foo_22:13379|foo_1:16132|foo_10:9330|foo_23:13913|foo_6:8314|foo_13:4967    
foo_13:4891|foo_5:22715|foo_2:12098|foo_8:18634|foo_23:1341|foo_4:13995|foo_16:2923|foo_10:13663|foo_7:22939|foo_14:16711|foo_25:17824  
foo_22:8180|foo_1:11974|foo_7:6660|foo_17:17839|foo_10:3605|foo_8:22439|foo_6:15494|foo_11:17924|foo_18:17351|foo_20:16627|foo_14:9223|foo_13:2538|foo_16:19077 
foo_12:11381|foo_24:541|foo_13:13106|foo_7:6459|foo_11:6398|foo_14:23127|foo_9:15701""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, names=['text'])

dfs = df['text'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().str.split(':', expand=True).reset_index()\
    .set_index(['level_0',0])[1].unstack()

print(dfs)
```

Output:

```
0        foo_1 foo_10 foo_11 foo_12    foo_13 foo_14 foo_15  foo_16 foo_17 foo_18  ... foo_23 foo_24   foo_25  foo_3  foo_4   foo_5  foo_6  foo_7  foo_8  foo_9
level_0                                                                            ...                                                                         
0          NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN  14896    NaN    1611    NaN    NaN  ...  17988    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN   14729  13008    NaN   2565    NaN
1          NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   5996    NaN     NaN   6127  13236  ...    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2         2589    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN  20227   12739    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  20010     5204  20030  12561  5494     3489    NaN  19129    NaN
3        13178    NaN    NaN   3307     22588  21537    NaN    2039    NaN    NaN  ...   3606    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN   15104    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4        16132   9330    NaN    NaN  4967        NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  13913    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN   10620   8314    NaN    NaN    NaN
5          NaN  13663    NaN    NaN      4891  16711    NaN    2923    NaN    NaN  ...   1341    NaN  17824      NaN  13995   22715    NaN  22939  18634    NaN
6        11974   3605  17924    NaN      2538   9223    NaN  19077   17839  17351  ...    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  15494   6660  22439    NaN
7          NaN    NaN   6398  11381     13106  23127    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    541      NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN   6459    NaN  15701
```

Comment: I think you can skip `apply` and do `df['text'].str.split('|', expand=True).replace(":\d+", "", regex=True)` directly.

Comment: It is close but each foo_xxx should have its own column.  So on row #1 foo_18 would then occupy column 7, foo_17 should take 8, foo_14 is the same as (0,0) so it would occupy column 0.  I'll add an edit to the original posting to show the sparseness..

Comment: @Belgrath. now I am confused.  Do you need the number after the colon? Or do you just want the foo_xx?

Comment: @Belgrath What do you want to do with the duplicate foo_12 values in Row 7?

Comment: The number after the foo is required, the foo__ value is basically the column header.

Comment: @ScottBoston This is great, exactly what I was looking to do!